# share a link about location in email

Tags: email, letter-writing

I want to write an email and apply for a "call for projects". I want to share the google map link of the location that I want to run the project at in my email.

Are these sentences correct? Which is the best sentence?

> For more information about the location, please follow the link below.
>
> For displaying location, please follow the link below.
>
> For have information about location, please follow the link below.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because, in the words of @tchrist, 'We are not a writing-help ... site; we're a site for linguists....' If you have a specific concern about part of one of the sentences, please give it.

Comment: You could leverage the internet more effectively. Make a regular part of the sentence into a hyperlink. People know how that works. Using brackets for the underline, "We're have a [kick-off meeting] at [PeeWee's Playhouse]." Includes all the information about the meeting time and date under the word meeting, and the location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is correct. You might also consider: "For a map of the location, please follow the link below."

"For have information about location, please follow the link below." is not correct.  It could be corrected to something like "To get more information, click the link below."   but I prefer the first suggestion.

Comment: Hello, Toby. Please read the above comment. I usually downvote answers to questions I consider very obviously off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

Sentence 1 is fine. The other two are not: to not for, display not displaying, the location not location.

Comment: Many thanks dear Toby and Jeremy for your responses.